# Does Parse.com offer the same login functionality with web applications as it does for mobile devices?

Tags: web-applications, authentication, parse-platform

I am making a database for use in my company. I will need to be able to set it up so that users can log in to access information from our database whether they are logging in from a mobile device or from a web browser. There will be separate apps for mobile and web. I am finding plenty of topics and applications for built in parse functions that make a login screen incredibly easy to implement, but I am not finding anything for web based applications. I would like to use that same functionality if I could as it automatically implements a lot of error handling and security for me. Does any one know if that will be possible? And if so, can you point me in the direction I would need to go to get help implementing that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes as you can see in their docs https://parse.com/docs/js_guide the Javascript SDK is what you would use to create websites